# Create a simple matrix with a for loop in python

Tags: for-loop, matrix

I try to create a matrix in python that should look like this:

```
[[1,0,0],[1,1,0],[1,1,1]]
```

I have made the following code:

```
Matrix = [] 
Row = [0, 0, 0]
    for i in range(0,3):
    Row[i] += 1
    print(Row)
    Matrix.append(Row)
print(Matrix)
```

The print expression in the middle is just to check that the Row variable update as it should, which it does. But for some reason I get the following output:

```
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

I can't understand what I am doing wrong. Please help, much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

try something like this :

```
Matrix = []
for i in range(0,3):
    Row = [0, 0, 0]
    Row[i] += 1
    print(Row)
    Matrix.append(Row)
print(Matrix)
```

For every loop you do you were using the same instance of Row[], now it goes back to [0 ,0 ,0 ] every time.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Solved the problem by putting the Row variable inside the loop